# What does 기대를 갖은 채 자신들을 참고삼아 만든 것이 분명한 한국 프로그램에 참여하는 재미있는 상황이 벌어지고 있는 것이다. mean?

Tags: vocabulary

기대를 갖은 채 자신들을 참고삼아 만든 것이 분명한 한국 프로그램에 참여하는 재미있는 상황이 벌어지고 있는 것이다.

This sentence is so long I can't follow it. does 자신 mean confidence or self here??

이에 일본을 대표하는 아이돌 그룹이 자신들의 떨어진 인기를 회복하기 위해, 한국 아이돌처럼 뛰어난 실력을 기르기 위해, 동시에 이를 바탕으로 혹시라도 케이팝의 시장인 더 넓은 세계에서도 이름을 알릴 기회를 얻을 수 있을지 모른다는 기대를 갖은 채 자신들을 참고삼아 만든 것이 분명한 한국 프로그램에 참여하는 재미있는 상황이 벌어지고 있는 것이다.

https://www.huffingtonpost.kr/entry/story_kr_5b441366e4b0c523e261eb04

Comment: You shouldn't have cut the sentence before 기대를 갖은 채: [이를 바탕으로 ... 얻을 수 있을지 모른다는 기대] is a whole phrase, which is the object of 갖은.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

이에: hence, due to this (used to connect this sentence to the preceding one)

[일본을 대표하는 ... 프로그램에 참여하는] 재미있는 상황이 벌어지고 있는 것이다 : an interesting situation [...] is happening; or, "we are witnessing an interesting situation where ..."

OK, let's drill down into the [...] part:

일본을 대표하는 아이돌 그룹이: (subject) an idol group "representing" Japan; or, more naturally, "one of the most famous Japanese idol groups"

The following are three consecutive phrases describing the "reason" of this idol group's behavior:

자신들의 떨어진 인기를 회복하기 위해: in order to regain their sliding fame

한국 아이돌처럼 뛰어난 실력을 기르기 위해: to gain competence(?) that matches those of Korean idols

동시에 이를 (= 한국 프로그램에 참여) 바탕으로 혹시라도 [케이팝의 시장인 ... 기회]를 얻을 수 있을지 모른다는 기대를 갖은 채: at the same time, with an anticipation that they could find [an opportunity to ...] based on this (= participating in this Korean program)

- Now look at the [...] again:

  케이팝의 시장인 더 넓은 세계에서도 이름을 알릴 기회: an opportunity to advertise themselves to the broader world that is the market for K-pop

  (이름을 알리다 = "let one's name known" = become famous, advertise oneself)

[자신들(=이 일본 그룹)을 참고삼아 만든 것이 분명한 한국 프로그램]에 참여하는: participating in a Korean program that was obviously inspired by themselves

- X를 참고(로) 삼다 = use X as a prototype/inspiration/reference
- X를 참고 삼아 만들다 = make (something) following the pattern of X / taking inspiration from X

Okay, that was a long sentence.  Putting it back together:

> As a result, we're witnessing an interesting situation where one of the most famous Japanese idol groups is participating in a Korean program that was obviously created by taking inspiration from the group itself, in order to regain their sliding fame, to gain competence matching those of Korean idols, and with an anticipation that this could allow them an opportunity to advertise themselves to the broader world that is the market for K-Pop.

...Phew.

Answer (score 0):

(기대를 갖은 채) (자신(self)들을 참고 삼아 만든 것이) (분명한 한국 프로그램에 참여하는 재미있는 상황이 벌어지고 있는 것이다)

참고 삼아 만들다 = make roughly for exercise : If it fails, then it is okay (not bad). And if it does a success, then it is fine.

Because they are collected with no exact goal, it is absolutely interesting that they participated in Korean program with a dreamy expection.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. could you re-phrase the original sentence in korean?